# How can I show a list of comma-separated related model titles using Phalcon's Volt templates?

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I want to display a list of related models in my view, as a comma-separated list.

Say I have a Posts model, and related Tags, `post.getTags()` gets the related models but I can't see how to then concatenate them in a way that will produce the right output.

In plain PHP views, I'd simply put the HTML into an array and `implode(', ', $tagLinks)`.

How can I achieve the same output with Volt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as I wanted to get formatted information from a model, I couldn't just use a plain implode() or join filter. As suggested by Eugene, I added a custom function to the Volt engine, and a method to my Model to get the correctly-formatted info.

Custom Volt function (in an App\Formatter class I'd already got for other view-related formatting):

```
static public function joinModels($resultset, $function, $join = ', ')
{
    $result = '';
    foreach ($resultset as $item) {
        $result .= $item->$function() . $join;
    }
    return substr($result, 0, strlen($join) * -1);
}
```

Added it to Volt:

```
$compiler = $volt->getCompiler();
$compiler->addFunction('joinModels', 'App\\Formatter::joinModels');
```

And in the Model:

```
public function linkTo()
{
    return Phalcon\Tag::linkTo('tags/' . urlencode($this->name), htmlspecialchars($this->name));
}
```

Then, finally, in my view:

```
{% set postTags = post.getTags() %}
{% if postTags.count() %}
    {{ joinModels(postTags, 'linkTo') }}
{% else %}
    None
{% endif %}
```

Many thanks to those that answered for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter inside your volt engine.

```
$compiler = $volt->getCompiler();
$compiler->addFilter('joiner', function($resolvedArgs, $exprArgs)  {
    $text = 'implode(", ", ' . $resolvedArgs  . ')';
    return $text;
});
```

and use that 'joiner' filter inside your template.

`{{ post.getTags() | joiner }}`

finally. if you too lazy to create a filter or function then just type php code. it's work on volt.

```
some tags : <?= implode(', ', $tagLinks) ?>
```

Edit:
I think volt already have `join` filter . see http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#filters

Answer (score 0):

There is join filter already: `{{ tagLinks|join(",") }}`

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't address how to access correctly-formatted data, unless I manually created `tagLinks` in the controller.